# React Native android fetch network request error

Tags: android, asp.net, react-native, networking, fetch

Okay I'm at my wits end here with this one.

So in my React-Native app, I am making a fetch request to an ASP.NET Core API hosted on my network.

In my API, I have configured the Conveyor VS Code extension and can access the API just fine with any device on my network using the following URL: `https://192.168.1.22:45455/api/users/login`

However, when running the app through Expo, it consistently gives me a Network request failed error when trying to access that url from within React-Native.

this is the actual fetch call:

```
const makeHeader = (token) => {
  return {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token};
}
const authenticate = async (token) => {
  try {
    let res = await fetch(constants.backendUrl + 'users/login', {headers: makeHeader(token)});
    let user = await res.json();
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Am I missing something in my fetch options?

Also, when calling the `authenticate` method, it actually goes through the then statement.

```
authenticateUser = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
      .then(token => {
        authenticate(token)
          .then(user => {
            console.log({user}); // This fires and returns undefined
            this.setState({user})
          })

      });
  }
```

Comment: try adding  'Content-Type': 'application/json' in the headers and add method: 'GET'

Comment: @MaStErNeWbIe Nope, still the same error

Comment: Pity I missed your question about Conveyor.  The problem was most likely the TLS certificate used for the HTTPS not being trusted.  We have a new release coming in a few days that addresses this.  Also you could use Conveyor's tunneling which provides a fully trusted certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my issue by doing the following steps:

- Disabled the Conveyor extension as it did not do what I needed it to do
- Edited the Visual Studio Project's `applicationhost.config` file and added the following lines

```
<bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:60787:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44378:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:60787:192.168.1.22" /> <!-- added this line -->
</bindings>
```

- Installed ngrok, and ran `ngrok http 60787 --host-header localhost` to forward the port.
- Changed the `constants.backendUrl` to whatever URL ngrok gave me, making sure to use http over https
- Opened Visual Studio Project as an Administrator, and ran IIS Express

I know that for iOS you need to use https in your fetch calls, but I am developing for Android currently, and for development purposes, this will work before I deploy the API.  I attempted to use https and React-Native did not accept the certificate for some reason.